# Understanding restriction in $S_3$

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Let $G=S_3$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& e & (123) & (12) \\ \hline
\chi_0 & 1 &1 & 1\\ \hline
\chi_1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ \hline
\chi_2 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Let $H=C_3$.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& e & (123) & (12) \\ \hline
\chi_0 & 1 &1 & 1\\ \hline
\chi_1 & 1 & \zeta & \zeta^2 \\ \hline
\chi_2 & 1 & \zeta^2 & \zeta \\ \hline
\end{array}

Then if $\chi=(a,b,c)$ is a representation of $G=S_3$, how does $Res_H\chi=(a,b,b)$?

Also I am not sure why (12) is a conjugacy class for $C_3$.

I know the definition $(Res_H\chi)(h)=\chi(h) \ \ \ \ \forall h \in H$.

Comment: What does $\chi=(a,b,c)$ mean? I guess you mean to say that $H=\langle (1,2,3)\rangle$ in which case you're right that $(1,2)$ is not in $H$, rather the last conjugacy class *representative* should be $(1,3,2)$.

Comment: @mt_ $\chi$ is the character, so I assume $\chi=(a,b,c)$ is a row in the above table

Comment: Then $\chi=(a,b,c)$ is a character, not a representation.  The point is that the conjugacy class reps for $H$ are $e,(1,2,3),(1,3,2)$ and if $\chi$ is a $S_3$ character, $\chi((1,2,3))=\chi((1,3,2))$ because 3-cycles are conjugate in $S_3$.  That's why $\operatorname{Res}\chi$ takes the same value on $(1,2,3)$ as on $(1,3,2)$ so that you get the $b$ twice.